# What a tester need to do when he found a bug and the dev does not want to fix it – and it is important

Tags: testing

Interview question. Please help what the tester need to do?

Answer (score 3):

The testers responsibility at that stage ends when the details of the bug are logged into whatever Bug Tracking tool is being used by the team.

At that point onwards, till the bug is fixed, it is the Development team owners responsibility.

Normally, the Dev team owner / test team leads etc would be triaging the bugs at regular intervals to decide on their priority.

Based on the priorities decided, its upto the Dev team lead to ensure the fixing of the bug.

The tester is really out of the loop till the bug is fixed and a new build supplied to the tester with that bug fix for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you file a bug you can set the priority of the bug. If you feel it is important then put the priority as high and explain why the priority is high.

Now if the develoment team does not want to fix, it means they think that it's chances of occurring at the customer side are less. So you will have to explain why customer can also face it.

If it is blocking issue for the testing and then mention like that and do nothing until it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you define **important**. One very common strategy is to find out the most used customer scenarios and if this bug is affecting those. As a tester one should think about the whole product experience and if this bug is interrupting the most basic system flows then its your duty as a tester to make sure it is fixed.

1. Your first step is to first try to be as objective as possible and collect the data, regarding user statistics, scenarios how often the bug could appear, %'s etc. This step is very important to present your case.
2. Then using this information try to rationalize with the dev on the importance of this bug.
3. If its not working still then you have to go another notch up and talk to your manager about this.
4. If he thinks that your case is valid and fights along with dev/dev team, its great.
5. Otherwise come back to step 1. Repeat 1-4 and if in meanwhile if you can find other teams or issues that bug can cause that will be additional benefit.

This answer is one of the several you could give in an interview. And you may have to vary depending on the interaction and other constraints. But this direction gives you a good start.

Comment: The role of the tester in most organisations is to find the bug, not prioritise the bug or make a case for fixing the bug. The project owner/manager has the job of prioritising the list and making the case.

Comment: Yes it depends largely on the organization and their culture. Since it was asked in the interview, I am thinking they are expecting an answer in these lines but depending on the company it differs, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

If developer denies fixing it for no proper reason, escalate to manager and raise severity. 
If it was management decision to allow the bug in that release but fix it later, then create a Ticket (production ticket or feature ticket) and track it. Mark it deferred it for now.